# How can I solve this error about TensorFlow environment?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have met the error as follows when I run some code of TFF:

my code:

```
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow_federated
```

---

```
import collections
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff

tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()
```

my Error:

```
ImportError: This version of TensorFlow Addons requires TensorFlow 
version >= 2.1.0; Detected an installation of version 1.15.0. Please upgrade 
TensorFlow to proceed.
```

My try:

I have tried to upgrade tensorflow to 2.1.0 but the same error appeared. And then I uninstall tensorflow and install it again, but there is no change with error output.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Upgrade TensorFlow and try again

Comment: Did you try to uninstall and then reinstall tff as well?

Comment: I tried to uninstall and then reinstall tff just now. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: I tried it, but the error also exists. It was OK in the morning but the error came up when I connected to the Colaboratory just now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue this morning.

What fixed it for me was uninstalling then re installing both tensorflow and the tensorflow-addons package.  Give that a try:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-addons
pip uninstall tensorflow

pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-addons
```

Answer (score 0):

uninstall version

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow
```

install latest version

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.15.2
```